# Mapping from integer to the ith array of non-decreasing digits

Tags: algorithm, combinatorics

Consider all arrays of length `n` of digits 0-9 in non-decreasing order.  There are `binom(9+n, n)` such arrays.  For a fixed `n`, we can consider the arrays in sorted order. I would like to be able to jump directly to the `i`th array in this order without explicitly enumerating all of them first.

How can you do this?

Comment: One idea would be to pre-calculate the number of arrays starting with each digit. That would let you start enumerating closer to the target, with the first array entry starting with that digit. For a less distant match, pre-calculate every two digit start or even every three digit start.

Comment: Could you put in an example with the expected answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right about  number of arrays.

So we have to get combination in lexicographic order by its number.

Then match combination with array - difference between combination items (diminished by one) corresponds to array increment.

Example for array length 3.

I have no `math.comb` in my Python 3.7 library, so using own function `cnk` with the same signature.

```
#use math.comb instead for Python 3.8+
def cnk(n, k):
    k = min(k, n - k)
    if k <= 0:
        return 1 if k == 0 else 0
    res = 1
    for i in range(k):
        res = res * (n - i) // (i + 1)
    return res

def num2comb(n, k, m):  #combination by number in lex order
    res = []
    next = 1
    while k > 0:
        cn = cnk(n - 1, k - 1)
        if m < cn:
            res.append(next)
            k -= 1
        else:
            m -= cn
        n -= 1
        next += 1
    return res

def non_decreasing_arr(n, i):
    cmb = num2comb(n+9, n, i)
    minv = cmb[0]-1
    arr = [minv]
    for j in range(n-1):
        t = cmb[j+1]-cmb[j]-1+minv
        arr.append(t)
        minv = t
    return arr

nn = 3
for i in range(cnk(nn+9, nn)):
    arr = non_decreasing_arr(nn, i)
    print(i, arr)
```

Part of output:

```
0 [0, 0, 0]
1 [0, 0, 1]
2 [0, 0, 2]
..
10 [0, 1, 1]
11 [0, 1, 2]
12 [0, 1, 3]
...
129 [2, 6, 9]
130 [2, 7, 7]
131 [2, 7, 8]
132 [2, 7, 9]
...
217 [8, 8, 9]
218 [8, 9, 9]
219 [9, 9, 9]
```

Comment: Can you explain the different functions? For example, what is cnk computing? Is it math.comb(n, k)?

Comment: Yes, cnk might be changed to math.comb. numb2comb is recursive calculation of combination itself (set of k integers in range 1..n) using its index in lex order

Comment: You can use from scipy.special import comb in python 3.7

Comment: I don't understand. Code does work. Working method for building array from index is described. What's a reason to discuss negligible detail?

Answer (score 0):

To abstract your formula, given n digits which can take on k distinct values, there are binom(k+n-1, n) such sequences.

How many sequences start with digit d? Well, we have n-1 remaining digits, and k-d distinct values, so binom(k-d+n-2, n-1).

You can use binary search or just iterate (since there are only 10) to find out the first digit. Then, adjust your problem and repeat.

The adjustment is to reduce n by 1, and to reduce the target rank by the count that started with lower first digits. You also need to reduce the number of digits to the count remaining (i.e. the last digit used up to 9).